# What is the proper way to send a certificate to a web hosting company?

Tags: ssl-certificate, shared-hosting, wildcard-subdomain

I have a wildcard SSL cert issued through Azure. I need to use this certificate on a shared host (for a subdomain) and they don't have an interface for me to upload it myself, so I have to email it to them.

Azure exports the certificate without a password. Should I just send the PFX file or do I need to import to Windows and export with a password? What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: scp it to your host, and ask the hosting provider to pick it up from there?

Answer (score 1):

Certificates are public information, there is no need to password-protect them.

Private keys on the other hand need to be kept private and secured.